# How to select record except the lower values record against an value in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, where-clause

This is my table:

```
id (int), title, amount (int)
```

In the table there are records like this:

```
"1", "Package of 100$", "100"
"2", "Package of 200$", "200"
"3", "Package of 300$", "300"
"4", "Package of 400$", "400"
"5", "Package of 500$", "500"
"6", "Package of 600$", "600"
"7", "Package of 700$", "700"
```

Now I want to execute a mysql query to get record like this:

```
select * from table except amount of 300 and lower to that (means will not select 300 , 200 and 100 amount row of column.
```

I have tried this query:

```
Select id, title, amount from table where amount = (select max(amount) from table)

And the result is: id: "7", title: "package of 700$", Amount: "700"
```

But I want all the records that is upper than 300 amount.

How can I fetch record as I mentioned? 
I am just a beginner so please dont mind if I didn't make the question more clear. I think everyone cane understand what I mean, if no then I am sorry, but please give me an answer so I can dig into this more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want all the records that is upper than 300 amount.

Don't you just want to filter with a `where` clause?

```
select * from mytable where amount > 300
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE amount > 300;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
select
 * 
from table 
where amount > 300;
```